# How do you take a stratified random sample from a Pandas dataframe that stratifies by a continuous variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

Problem: I have a large Pandas dataframe with 1,000,000 rows, with a column for a continuous (floating point) feature *F* that varies between 0 and 1. The distribution of *F* is highly skewed in the data.

I want to take a random sample (without replacement) of N rows from the dataframe, weighted such that the histogram of *F* in the sample will be approximately uniform (or as close as possible to uniform!) between *F* = 0 and *F* = 1.

The obvious solution is

```
_ , sampleDF = train_test_split(bigDF, test_size = N, stratify = bigDF['F'] )
```

But this fails with an error message, presumably because `train_test_split` is only supposed to stratify with respect to a discrete or categorical variable.

> ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.

Ideally the solution to this would be fast and robust, and short as a bonus. I eventually came up with a solution involving `stats.gaussian_kde` to estimate the density of *F*, and then fed that density to `bigDF.sample(weights = 1/density)`, but it involved a lot of hand-tweaking, and in addition didn't seem to actually give a fully uniform distribution. I may try to write this up as an answer if no-one has a good solution.

Does anyone know a really good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need these imports:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import numpy as np
```

This is the function I am currently using:

```
def samplestrat(df, stratifying_column_name, num_to_sample, maxrows_to_est = 10000, bw_per_range = 50, eval_points = 1000 ):
    '''Take a sample of dataframe df stratified by stratifying_column_name
    '''
    strat_col_values = df[stratifying_column_name].values
    samplcol = (df.sample(maxrows_to_est)  if df.shape[0] > maxrows_to_est else df  )[stratifying_column_name].values
    vmin, vmax = min(samplcol), max(samplcol)
    pts = np.linspace(vmin,vmax  ,eval_points) 
    kernel = gaussian_kde( samplcol , bw_method = float(  (vmax - vmin)/bw_per_range  )   )
    density_estim_full = np.interp(strat_col_values, pts , kernel.evaluate(pts) )
    return df.sample(n=num_to_sample, weights = 1/(density_estim_full))
```

Testing on some synthetic data:

```
def sigmoid(x,mi, mx): return mi + (mx-mi)*(lambda t: (1+200**(-t+0.5))**(-1) )( (x-mi)/(mx-mi) )
toyDF = pd.DataFrame( data =  sigmoid(np.random.normal(loc = 10.0, scale = 1.0, size = 10000) , 7 , 13)  ,  columns=['val']  )
pd.DataFrame.hist(toyDF, column = 'val', bins =20 )
plt.show()
```

[image: distribution]

```
df_stratified_sample = samplestrat(toyDF, 'val', 1500 )
pd.DataFrame.hist(df_stratified_sample, column = 'val', bins =20 )
plt.show()
```

[image: distribution after stratified]

This isn't perfect, but as we can see we get a relatively good approximation to a uniform distribution.